# Symbol enlargement

Tags: symbols

How can I write code where I can grow each of these symbols without removing existing packages?

[image]

**For example I was able to write the following code to enlarge the "small" symbol:**

```
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardless=\mathcode`<
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoless}{
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@less\relax}
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@less}[2]{
  \raisebox{-0.03\height}{\scalebox{1.35}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardless$}}
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`< \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoless
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`<="8000 }
\makeatother
```

I want to write this code in other symbols

**My Code:**

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[\neq,\leq,\geq,\Rightarrow,\times,\circ,\cup,\cap,\subset,\supset,\in,\equiv\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The symbols you present aren't unique to `MnSymbol`. Why not stick to the regular font symbols (that should be a bit larger) rather than including an entirely new symbol font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to scale up the symbols. You can do it by redeclaring the font shapes introducing a magnification factor.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolA10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolB}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolB9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolB10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolB12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolB}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolB-Bold12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolD9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolD10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolD12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolD-Bold12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolE10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolF9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolF10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolF12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolF-Bold12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{MnSymbolS}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolS9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolS10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolS12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{MnSymbolS}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.3] MnSymbolS-Bold12}{}

\begin{document}

\[A<,\neq,\leq,\geq,\Rightarrow,\times,\circ,\cup,\cap,\subset,\supset,\in,\equiv\]

\end{document}
```

[image]